# If the integral $\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx$ converges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f(x+n)\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let be $f:[0, \infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a measurable function such that $$\int_0^{\infty}x\cdot f(x)\,dx< \infty.$$
Show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f(x+n)\, dx<\infty .$$

#### Progress

The only thing I proved is that $n\cdot \int_0^{\infty}f(x+n)dx\rightarrow 0$. Clearly it is not enough.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it. The only thing i proved is that $n\cdot \int_0^{\infty}f(x+n)dx\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty.$ Clearly it is not enough.

Comment: You might (also) want to make your sums and integrals start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: For the sum you're right, I dont't think I need to take the integral from 1.

Comment: As you wish, except that the behavior of $f$ on $(0,1)$ is now irrelevant, so keeping the hypothesis as it is can only help to confuse things. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with the function $f(x) = \dfrac 1x$ for $0 < x \le 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

If the sum starts at $n=1$, use $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(x+n) \, dx = \int_n^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty \chi_{[n,\infty)}(x) f(x) \, dx$ along with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{[n,\infty)}(x) \le x$.

Comment: Ok, take the sum from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: +1. Exercise for the OP: Show the reverse implication (once the hypothesis is corrected).